# Using find to filter array with two arguments

Tags: arrays, typescript, filter, angular6

I'm trying to filter my array of objects passing two parameters but it's not working... My array contain an object with the values that I'm passing on parameters but the result is empty

```
const item = this.lista.find(i => i.number === rule.number &&  i.name === rule.name);
```

I also tried to use "filter" but same problem...

```
const item = this.lista.filter(i => i.number === rule.number).filter(i => 
 i.name === rule.name);
```

Here is my full array:

```
  this.lista= [
            {number: 0, name: 'jose'},
            {number: 2, name: 'maria'},
            {number: 3, name: 'martha'},
            {number: 4, name: 'ana'},
            {number: 4, name: 'petter'},
        ];
```

And this is the rule object:

```
rule = new Rule();
rule.number = 4;
rule.name = 'ana';
```

There's a best way to do this?

Comment: What does the array and rule look like?

Comment: Is it possible that your array doesn't have a single item that matches `rule` in both name and number?

Comment: sorry @Aron that answer was wrong...
This is the right

"rule" is an object that I'm using to compare 
And this is how my array looks like:
[
            {number: 0, name: 'jose'},
            {number: 2, name: 'maria'},
]

Comment: Sure. But either way, is it possible that your array doesn't have a single item that matches rule in both name and number?

Comment: No, If I can filter by name and number I'll find only one item but the problem is that my filters and the way that I'm trying to find the object inthe array os not working...

Comment: Can you post the full array and the full rule object?

Comment: sure, I'll edit my question

Comment: Does my answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is in your code but I've reproduced a simple example of your code and it works just as expected.

```js
const rule = {};
rule.number = 4;
rule.name = 'ana';

const lista = [{
    number: 0,
    name: 'jose'
  },
  {
    number: 2,
    name: 'maria'
  },
  {
    number: 3,
    name: 'martha'
  },
  {
    number: 4,
    name: 'ana'
  },
  {
    number: 4,
    name: 'petter'
  },
];

const item = lista.find(i => i.number === rule.number && i.name === rule.name);

console.log(item);
```

Comment: If the code in the question is working as expected, please close it as no MCVE OR no longer reproducible.